# add onto checked values in checkbox via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Im trying to add onto a checkbox's values selected, so maintain the selected values but add other selected values. however the attribute doesn't add selected values. here is my attempt (p.s how would I in turn remove values selected and keep existing values selected?) thanks

```
$('.add_button').click(function() {

            var values = $('input:checkbox:checked.ssremployeeids').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get(); 

         $('.ssremployeeid').attr('selected',values);


       <div class="grs-multi-select-area" style="height:120px;width:150px;">
  <div class="grs-multi-select-box ">
  <input id="ssrBox" class="ssremployeeid" type="checkbox" name="ssremployeeid[]"
 value="1312">
      Amanda Becker
   </div>
   <div class="grs-multi-select-box "> // same as above I just collapsed it for viewing purposes
   <div class="grs-multi-select-box ">
   <div class="grs-multi-select-box ">
   </div> //closes main div 

    });
```

Comment: I am confused. What needs to be added and what needs to be removed. Too much add/remove going on in your question.:D

Comment: @Learner sorry for the confusion edited the question again. thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to get values of selected items and then assign them back?

Comment: So, you want to clear values variable?

Comment: @Learner actually Im grabbing all the currently selected values (get stored in the values var), then I have a button in which Im suppose to add to the other checkboxes's exisitng selected values

Comment: Checkboxes keep their state if you don't reload the page, so what are you trying to do?!?!

Comment: "how would I in turn remove values selected" - selected where? "keep existing values selected" - selected where?

Comment: @Learner grabbing all the currently selected values from one checkbox(get stored in the values var), then I have a button in which Im suppose to add to the other checkboxes's exisitng selected values

Comment: So, basically you want to grab all the selected values from one set of checkboxes to another set of checkboxes?

Comment: @Learner yes precisly sorry about the vague question

Comment: Please post your HTML which has both sets of checkboxes

Comment: @Learner I posted it, thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32968/discussion-between-learner-and-squirtle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure if I understood you question correctly, but based one what I understood here's something you could try:

**Sample Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/HFULf/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="val1" checked="checked" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="val2"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" value="val3"/>
</div>
<div id="div2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="val1"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="val2"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" value="val3"/>
</div>

<button id="btn1">Add Selected</button>
<button id="btn2">Remove Selected</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
//add selected values from first set of check-boxes to the second set
$('#btn1').click(function(e){
    $('div#div1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){   
        $('div#div2  input[type="checkbox"]').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked',true);
    });
});

//remove values from second set of check-boxes if selected in first one
$('#btn2').click(function(e){
    $('div#div1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){   
        $('div#div2  input[type="checkbox"]').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked',false);
    });
});
```

Hope, this will help you a little if not solve your problem entirely.